# React or statements with functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSX statement that renders props like so:

`<span>{rentRate || quotedSeatCharges}</span>`

Which renders just fine. However, I have a function that prepends a currency name/symbol before it which formats it:

```
const formatCost = (cost) => {
    if (currencySymbol) return `${currencySymbol}${cost}`
    return `${currencyName} ${cost}`
}
```

And I've tried calling it like so:

`<span>{formatCost(rentRate || quotedSeatCharges)}</span>`

Which works for the first prop, but doesn't work for the second one.
[image]

I've also tried

`<span>{formatCost(rentRate) || formatCost(quotedSeatCharges)}</span>`

Which still works for the first prop, but the second prop ends up being `null`.

I've also tried making those two props into one at the parent level like so:

```
rentSeatCost={rentRate}
rentSeatCost={quotedSeatCharges}
```

and then in the child component:

`formatCost(rentSeatCost)`

but only works for the first prop and doesn't do anything for the second, just like the first attempt.

Is there a way to be able to do this in my method? Or should I just give up and find an alternative?

Comment: Why are you trying to roll your own? [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) exists....e.g. `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(2304718) === "$2,304,718.00"`

Comment: @JaredSmith If it were up to me, that's what I would do. However, I'm not the one that had implemented this, and the project is asking for currency name.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the point of your `||`? You're saying you "want to render both" you want to render both `formatCost(rentRate)` and `formatCost(quotedSeatCharges)`? Or you want to render either one with both USD and $? Can you post the code for this component? Why not just spit out both from the formatCost function? `formatCost(rentRate, quotedSeatCharge)`

Comment: @JaredSmith However, thank you for that link! That would've definitely helped in the beginning stages of this project had I joined earlier.

Comment: You're quite welcome, the international api is one of the best things in Javascript that no one knows about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I stopped looking at the child component and looked at the parent above. I was rendering the child component twice and turns out I was passing in `currencySymbol` and `currencyName` in only one of the two components, which is why the other one wasn't being prepended with both currencies.

Thank you everyone for taking the time to look into this. It was my own oversight.

Answer (score 1):

Print out your currencyName and currencySymbol variables, they must not be set when the function gets called.

Comment: How is this different ?

Comment: I might just manually print it out as a last resort like you've mentioned. Just wanted to see if there is a way around this method.

Comment: well, just in debug mode - if you console.log(currencySymbol) in your format cost function, does it give you the symbol you expect for both?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a ternary like `rentRate ? formatCost(rentRate) : formatCost(quotedSeatCharges)`

hope it helps

thank you

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to render both, not one or the other.

Comment: like this `{formatCost(rentRate) && formatCost(quotedSeatCharges)}` ?

Comment: hmm... you should handle the two arguments in your function

Comment: Looking at your first statement, `<span>{rentRate || quotedSeatCharges}</span>`, seems like only one of those would render. But you're trying to render both?